# Problems connecting SimpleAuth with podfile

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile

[image: my issue]

I connected Simpleauth but after the build up there are a lot of errors

I use Xcode 8.3.1  swift 3. iOS 10.2

Comment: I use pod file, download without errors

Comment: go through project directory on terminal and fire command : pod update I think you have downloaded this project right?

Comment: @AshokLondhe I create this project,i try update & try create another project but have same issue

Comment: give please pod file name - pod which you used in pod file.

Comment: @AshokLondhe. pod 'SimpleAuth/Instagram'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'


like this

Comment: I am installing pods on my system then will update you